# Toast when fields are Empty in Application

Tags: android, android-toast

I want to display toast when fields are empty.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            aut.signInWithEmailAndPassword(edittext1.getText().toString(), edittext2.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, _aut_sign_in_listener);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Why you comment all answer with 'Thank you for your response.problem solved'? Just some answer are correct, not all!

Comment: @AbnerEscócio Actually this is my first question on this site, and I'm overwhelmed to see these much replies in instant. Will take your advice!

Comment: If any of the answers have helped you, select the one that's helped you most by clicking the ✔ icon underneath the score. This will mark the question as "answered", and you and the answerer will receive reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of toast, **"setError"** to edit texts. It would be better

```
editText.setError("This field can not be blank");
```

Answer (score 3):

Before doing that

```
aut.signInWithEmailAndPassword(edittext1.getText().toString(), edittext2.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, _aut_sign_in_listener)
```

Try to check if data is empty as follow

```
if (edittext1.getText().toString().isEmpty() || edittext2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"fill the required field",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    aut.signInWithEmailAndPassword(edittext1.getText().toString(), edittext2.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, _aut_sign_in_listener)
}
```

Comment: Aditionally to correct @Pritam's answer use `TextUtils.isEmpty(edittext1.getText().toString())` instead `.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

When the fields are empty, apply this check :-

```
if (edittext1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Edit text 1 can not be empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

else if (edittext2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Edit text 2 can not be empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
    else{
     //success code here
        aut.signInWithEmailAndPassword(edittext1.getText().toString(), edittext2.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, _aut_sign_in_listener);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(edittext1.getText().toString().length()<=0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "email is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if (edittext2.getText().toString().length()<=0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "password is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            aut.signInWithEmailAndPassword(edittext1.getText().toString(), edittext2.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, _aut_sign_in_listener);
        }
    }

});
```